# returning count of dates to be grouped by customer ID

Tags: sql

In order to calculate the target column nbr_months_active,
the following query was used:

```
  select
    customerid,
    count(
      distinct(
        DATE_PART(y, cast(invoicedate as date)) || '-' || LPAD(
          DATE_PART(mon, cast(invoicedate as date)),
          2,
          '00'
        )
      )
    )
```

The data looks like this...

```
InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,12/1/2010 8:26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom
536365,71053,WHITE METAL LANTERN,6,12/1/2010 8:26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
536365,84406B,CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER,8,12/1/2010 8:26,2.75,17850,United Kingdom
```

I did not understand exactly what the query is returning.
It must be returning the correct values because the query is mentioned on a reputed site.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-multi-class-classification-models-with-amazon-redshift-ml/

I will like to know what is the count returned for each customer-ID and how is that going to help to build a model?

Comment: It's just calculating a 'year-month' string for each row and then counting the distinct instances of that string found.  The result is the number of distinct 'year-month' values found in the data.  You didn't show the entire SQL.  Because of the `customerid` in the `select` list, there must have been a `GROUP BY customerid`.  So the calculation is per customerid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is turning a date column into a format YYYY-MM in order to count distinct values.  However, it is using a very arcane method to do something that should be simpler.

If `invoice_date` is already a date or timestamp, you can use:

```
select customerid,
       count(distinct date_trunc('month', invoice_date))
from t
group by customerid;
```

If for some reason it needs to be converted to a date, then you can do that:

```
select customerid,
       count(distinct date_trunc('month', cast(invoice_date as date)))
from t
group by customerid;
```

Comment: Also, don't forget the `COUNT` requires both the year and month to avoid confusion between the same month in different years.